# Do any of you who are *really* dealing with APT have any recommended intelligence feeds for SIEM/IDS/etc?

Tags: ids, siem

This question about Advanced Persistent Threats (APT) was posted by [Rich Mogull](http://securosis.com/about/team) on twitter.  I copied it here because I'm curious too.

Rich posted these follow-up tweets:

> And by APT I mean ***real*** APT.... China specific stuff.
>   Netwitness/Mandiant/HBGary type stuff.
>   Really specialize in this. Most of what I've seen is very custom.

Comment: Original twitter post is: http://twitter.com/#!/rmogull/status/22019761063854082

Comment: Perhaps amending "dealing with APT" to "dealing with the possibility of APT" would qualify more answers--it's my understanding that most security professionals who are actually dealing with APT have some very strong NDEs about it.

Comment: The APT I know is Automatic Programmed Tool - What does this acronym stand for?

Comment: I'm guessing, like user502 there, that people really doing this work can't talk about it, due to NDAs or something stronger.  DAve, he's talking about the Advanced Persistent Threat (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Persistent_Threat).

Comment: I know the bits I have done in the past on this, but am interested in anything that can be disclosed, under an anonymous user ID if need be. Popped a wee bounty up to see if it will spur anyone on.

Comment: Can the question be edited to explain the terms a little more?  There is no twitter URL or quote in the question and it is all abbreviations.  Should I (we) know these abbreviations?  I might be the only one confused, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the sensitive nature of APT and that it is closely aligned to espionage, the only real way to get a suitable feed will be through Government or National Law Enforcement agencies.

The difficulty will be in establishing a level of trust to enable the sharing of information.

For organisations within the USA, the advice is to contact your local FBI field office and arrange for a threat briefing on the subject.

For organisations within the UK, then making contact with CPNI (Centre for the Protection of National Infrastructure) would be the best option. CPNI hold a number of industry specific 'Information Exchange' forums that may be of help. However it is worth noting that CPNI has a focus on the critical national infrastructure for the UK and if your organisation falls outside of this may impact on access to that.

Comment: France: check with ANSSI.
Germany: check with BSI.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether they have specific SIEM/IDS feeds, but a good intelligence source historically has been iDefense (now part of Verisign - http://labs.idefense.com/).

Historically (prior to the security research they're more well known for now) iDefense were a commercial intelligence organisation, and spent a lot of time tracking organised crime and malware groups on behalf of their clients.

Answer (score 1):

Post HBGary getting owned, it appears that [endgames.us](http://endgames.us) offers these services.

Personally, I would go with combining DShield with SHODAN data and start building your own.t